# Why is the exec command output exceeding `65536` truncated when `exec.Cmd.Stdout` and `cmd.Stderr` point to the same `bytes.Buffer`?

Tags: go

Why is the exec command output exceeding `65536` truncated when `exec.Cmd.Stdout` and `cmd.Stderr` point to the same `bytes.Buffer` like below?

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "os"
    "os/exec"

    "k8s.io/klog/v2"
)

func main() {
    klog.Infof("==============1==================")
    args := []string{"bucket", "stats"}

    execCmd := exec.Command("radosgw-admin", args...)
    f, err := os.Create("xxxx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    execCmd.Stdout = f

    err = execCmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    f.Close()

    bs, err := os.ReadFile("xxxx")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    klog.Infof("exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: %d", len(bs))

    klog.Infof("==============2==================")
    execCmd = exec.Command("radosgw-admin", args...)
    var b bytes.Buffer
    execCmd.Stdout = &b

    err = execCmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    klog.Infof("exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: %d", b.Len())

    klog.Infof("==============3==================")
    execCmd = exec.Command("radosgw-admin", args...)
    var b2 bytes.Buffer
    execCmd.Stdout = &b2
    execCmd.Stderr = &b2   // <== here

    err = execCmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    klog.Infof("exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: %d", b2.Len())

    klog.Infof("==============4==================")
    execCmd = exec.Command("radosgw-admin", args...)
    f, err = os.Create("yyyy")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    execCmd.Stdout = f
    execCmd.Stderr = f

    err = execCmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    f.Close()

    bs2, err := os.ReadFile("yyyy")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    klog.Infof("exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: %d", len(bs2))
    
    klog.Infof("==============5==================")
    execCmd = exec.Command("radosgw-admin", args...)
    var b3 bytes.Buffer
    var b4 bytes.Buffer
    execCmd.Stdout = &b3
    execCmd.Stderr = &b4

    err = execCmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    klog.Infof("exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: %d, err: %d", b3.Len(), b4.Len())
}
```

The output:

```
root@node01:/# ./test 
I1207 10:53:47.150299   57435 test.go:36] ==============1==================
I1207 10:53:48.800277   57435 test.go:56] exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: 404237
I1207 10:53:48.803742   57435 test.go:64] ==============2==================
I1207 10:53:50.421419   57435 test.go:73] exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: 404237
I1207 10:53:50.421446   57435 test.go:76] ==============3==================
I1207 10:53:52.537304   57435 test.go:86] exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: 65536
I1207 10:53:52.537343   57435 test.go:89] ==============4==================
I1207 10:53:55.030006   57435 test.go:108] exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: 404237
I1207 10:53:55.035473   57435 test.go:115] ==============5==================
I1207 10:53:58.429107   57435 test.go:126] exec.Command(radosgw-admin bucket stats), length: 404237, err: 0
```

```
root@node01:/# radosgw-admin bucket stats | wc -c
404237
```

The output should be euqal to others.

Comment: A bytes.Buffer isn’t thread safe by itself.

Comment: @coxley Yes, but the command should ensure that the buffer Write method is not called concurrently because execCmd.Stdout == execCmd.Stderr.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. but I have three questions need to clarify.

1. The command is executed successfully, so no bytes write to stderr.
2. The standard library `cmd.CombinedOutput` also do it like this. https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/os/exec/exec.go#L1002-L1012
3. Why is the written data length 65536 and not others?